# How to get a white border for an rounded image in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am using the following method to get the rounded image. I want my image to have a white border. How can I get this? can anyone suggest for this.

```
dispImage=ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(resized, 150);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(dispImage);


public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
//        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(10, 10, bitmap.getWidth()-10, bitmap.getHeight()-10);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your code, after drawBitmap() call:

```
final int whiteColor = 0xffffff;
paint.setColor(whiteColor);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth((float) borderSizePx);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will helpful to you.

```
public Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int color, int cornerDips, int borderDips, Context context) {
    mContext = context;

    System.out.println("in rounded corner bitmap: "+color);

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int borderSizePx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) borderDips,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    final int cornerSizePx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) cornerDips,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    // prepare canvas for transfer
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerSizePx, cornerSizePx, paint);

    // draw bitmap
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    // draw border
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth((float) borderSizePx);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerSizePx, cornerSizePx, paint);

    return output;
}
```

get rounded bitmap using this:

```
bm=getRoundedCornerBitmap(bm,color, 10, 20, mContext);
```

passed color like below:

```
Color.argb(255, 199, 153, 29) or Color Hexvalue
```